# Knockout + Moment.js – Update relative dates inside an observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs

Inside my list of completed tasks, I used Moment.js's `fromNow()` to list the relative date of completion for each task. Here's the task model:

```
Task.Model = function(data) {
   this.id = data.id;
   this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
   this.status = ko.observable(data.status);
   this.completed = ko.observable(moment(data.date_completed).fromNow());
};
```

The relative date shows up, but the minutes never update, unless I refresh. Is there any way to update that observable?

Comment: What do you mean on "never update, unless I refresh"? Who and why should update it? How do you "refresh" the browser with F5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have an observable which tracks the current time, then compute the completed text based on that time:

```
var now = ko.observable(new Date());
setInterval(function() { now(new Date()); }, 60 * 1000);

var completedText = ko.computed(function()
    moment(data.date_completed).from(now()));
});
```